# Excel VBA open first returned google page - weird behavior

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel VBA to open the first returned page of google result. From the first page, I am manipulating the data based on their element IDs. On doing this process, I am encountering a pretty weird behavior.

Let me give a brief overview of what am trying to do.

I will get the first name and the last name as input in the user form. For the given first name and last name, I will search for the linkedin profile.

For example, if the first name is Sachin and last name is Tendulkar, I will use VBA to pass the search term as **Sachin Tendulkar linkedin** to the google.  For the search results returned, I will open the first search result page and try to get the linkedin profile data.

My code so far is as below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim RegEx As RegExp, RegMatch As MatchCollection
Dim MyStr As String
Dim pDisp As Object
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim sample As String
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Set RegEx = New RegExp
Dim iedoc As Object
Dim openedpage As String
Dim inpagestrt, inpageend As Integer
Dim returnstatement As String
Dim detailname, locationdetails, profileexperience, profilecontact
Dim overview,skillslist, profilelanguages, profileeducation, publicgroups
detailname = ""
returnstatement = ""
locationdetails = ""
profileexperience = ""
profilecontact = ""
overview = ""
skillslist = ""
profilelanguages = ""
profileeducation = ""
publicgroups = ""

FirstName = TextBox1.Value
LastName = TextBox2.Value
ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & FirstName & "+" & LastName & "+linkedin&meta="
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
MyStr = ie.Document.body.innerText
Set RegMatch = RegEx.Execute(MyStr)

'If a match to our RegExp searchstring is found then launch this page
If RegMatch.Count > 0 Then
ie.Navigate RegMatch(0)
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
'****************************************
'EDITS
'****************************************
Set iedoc = ie.Document
Dim extractedHTML As String
Dim iStart, iEnd As Integer
extractedHTML = iedoc.getElementById("search").innerHTML
iStart = InStr(1, extractedHTML, "href=", vbTextCompare) + Len("href=") + 1
iEnd = InStr(iStart, extractedHTML, Chr(34), vbTextCompare)
'extract the text
extractedHTML = Mid(extractedHTML, iStart, iEnd - iStart)
'go to the URL
ie.Navigate extractedHTML
Set iedoc1 = ie.Document
'MsgBox iedoc1
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("name").innerText
detailname = "NAME:" & vbCrLf & FirstName + " " + LastName
MsgBox ""
openedpage = ""
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("headline").innerText
'On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
MsgBox "LOCATION DETAILS:" & vbCrLf & openedpage
locationdetails = openedpage + vbCrLf
MsgBox locationdetails
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-experience").innerText
profileexperience = openedpage + vbCrLf
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-contact").innerText
profilecontact = openedpage + vbCrLf
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("overview").innerText
overview = openedpage + vbCrLf
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("skills-list").innerText
skillslist = openedpage + vbCrLf
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-languages").innerText
profilelanguages = openedpage + vbCrLf
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-education").innerText
profileeducation = openedpage + vbCrLf
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("pubgroups").innerText
publicgroups = openedpage + vbCrLf
returnstatement = locationdetails + profileexperience + profilecontact + overview + skillslist + profilelanguages + profileeducation + publicgroups
MsgBox returnstatement

ErrHandler:
   openedpage = "NULL"
 Resume Next

'****************************************
'End EDITS
'****************************************

Else
MsgBox "No linkedin profile found"
End If

Set RegEx = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

The weirdest thing is when I comment line number 59, my location details are returned as NULL. However, if I have that message box the location details are getting returned correctly. I tried using a variable instead of message box but the location details becomes NULL for all the scenarios except when I use the message box.

```
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("name").innerText
detailname = "NAME:" & vbCrLf & FirstName + " " + LastName
**MsgBox ""** (If i comment it out, location details becomes NULL. If it is uncommented, location details value is correct. 
openedpage = ""
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("headline").innerText
'On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
**MsgBox "LOCATION DETAILS:" & vbCrLf & openedpage**
locationdetails = openedpage + vbCrLf
MsgBox locationdetails
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing that you macro need some additional time to load all (or some additional) data. If you have you MsgBox in place you unintentionally give the process some time before you find and close you MsgBox.

What if you put other kind of 'waiting' point (like `Application.Wait` or `Do...Loop`) instead of MsgBox. Please let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer takes some time to load and render a page. Add a line

```
Do While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
```

after the instruction `ie.Navigate extractedHTML`. You're already doing something similar when loading the first page:

```
ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & FirstName _
  & "+" & LastName & "+linkedin&meta="
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
```

although you should add a sleep instruction there, too.